# Deleting email that already sent and received by receiver

Tags: email, email-server, web-hosting

I'm kinda new and have the very basic knowledge for server, so I hope I'm not posting the question in the wrong place here. (and I'm not a native English speaker so bear with me)

So the question is,
is there any effect on the receiver when we delete some emails in the sent folder of the sender?
For example, when User A sends email to User B, and user B receives and reads it, then later user A deletes the same email later from their sent items, does it affect the email in question in user B's mailbox in any way?

Or do you have any reference so I can learn more about the related topic?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, mailboxes cannot be expected to be interconnected in that way.
User A sends a mail to User B. At this point one copy of the mail is stored in A's Sent folder, and one copy of the mail is sent to B's Inbox. A's operations on their copy of the mail have no effect on B's copy of the mail, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Answer for your question is  "NO". But you can Recall email which you sent.

It is possible when email is not read by user. In outlook It is possible. This option call

> Email Recalling

Using this option you can replace previous email using new email. Additionally you can delete previous email. If mail is already read, it will not be successful.

But remember that this might only work on an Exchange/Outlook premise

Comment: Recall is so limited that it might as well not exist. Messages must be unread. Not supported for recipients outside the Exchange organization, or most mobile devices. And the recall email that lingers in this case calls more attention to the message than not doing anything.